# Running function on more than one column in one strike

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

since I'm not very pro in Python I would like to know if, after defining a fuction, is possible to run it on every column of the dataframe that is a float, creating n-new columns with the name of the original one + the string "_Ret". I'm using live data downloaded from Yahoo finance but since I'm building a model, it would be useful to just change the names in p1 dataframe and then apply the function Return to every column of Close price.

```
import yfinance as yf
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd
from numpy import log as ln
from datetime import timedelta

p1 = yf.download(['FTSEMIB.MI','ENEL.MI'])['Close']
p1=p1.fillna(0)
p1.reset_index(inplace=True)

t=p1.iloc[-1,0]
LookB1=(t - relativedelta(years=5))
if (LookB1 in p1['Date'].values):
    LP= (t - relativedelta(years=5))
else:
    LP=(p1.loc[(pd.to_datetime(p1['Date'])
                     - pd.to_datetime(LookB1)).abs().idxmin(),
    'Date'])

seed_date = LP - timedelta(days=90)

if (seed_date in p1['Date'].values):
    seed = (LP - relativedelta(days=90))
else:
    seed =(p1.loc[(pd.to_datetime(p1['Date'])
                     - pd.to_datetime(seed_date)).abs().idxmin(),
    'Date'])

def Return(x):
     return ln(x.div(x.shift(3)))
```

#I want to apply the Return function to both FTSEMIB.MI and ENEL.MI columns to obtain 2 separate columns #named FTSEMIB_Ret and ENEL_Ret. In general I would like to create a code that apply the Return function to #all the float columns identified (since in my case I have even the Date column which is a datetime one).
#Is it possible?? Even other approaches to obtain the same output would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call your function only on float columns, you can do this:

```python
def foo(sr):
    return sr + 0.5

df = df.infer_objects()
fltCols = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype=='float64']
df[[f'{col}_Ret' for col in fltCols]] = df[fltCols].apply(foo)
```

Sample input:

```
         dt1  flt1  int1  flt2 obj1
0 2023-04-01   1.0     1   1.0  1.0
1 2023-04-02   2.0     2   2.0  2.0
2 2023-04-03   3.0     3   NaN  3.0
              dt1     flt1   int1     flt2    obj1
0  datetime64[ns]  float64  int64  float64  object
```

Output:

```
         dt1  flt1  int1  flt2  obj1  flt1_Ret  flt2_Ret  obj1_Ret
0 2023-04-01   1.0     1   1.0   1.0       1.5       1.5       1.5
1 2023-04-02   2.0     2   2.0   2.0       2.5       2.5       2.5
2 2023-04-03   3.0     3   NaN   3.0       3.5       NaN       3.5
              dt1     flt1   int1     flt2     obj1 flt1_Ret flt2_Ret obj1_Ret
0  datetime64[ns]  float64  int64  float64  float64  float64  float64  float64
```

Note the call to `infer_objects()` to convert columns that contain only float but have somehow gotten a Series dtype of `object` (for example).

---

If you want to capture all numeric columns (for example `int` as well as `float`), you can do this:

```python
df = df.infer_objects()
numCols = [col for col in df.columns if pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(df[col])]
df[[f'{col}_Ret' for col in numCols]] = df[numCols].apply(foo)
```

Output:

```
         dt1  flt1  int1  flt2  obj1  flt1_Ret  int1_Ret  flt2_Ret  obj1_Ret
0 2023-04-01   1.0     1   1.0   1.0       1.5       1.5       1.5       1.5
1 2023-04-02   2.0     2   2.0   2.0       2.5       2.5       2.5       2.5
2 2023-04-03   3.0     3   NaN   3.0       3.5       3.5       NaN       3.5
              dt1     flt1   int1     flt2     obj1 flt1_Ret int1_Ret flt2_Ret obj1_Ret
0  datetime64[ns]  float64  int64  float64  float64  float64  float64  float64  float64
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! What if I want to create n- new variables with another function? I want now compute the Standartd Deviation on a part of the dataframe using the _Ret columns. I want n- Standard deviation variables (taking the Obj name and ending with _SD) as the number of _Return column in the dataframe. I tried to adapt the script you showed me but I didn't succeed. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what you're asking. Can you post a new question that explains in a little more detail? Feel free to link the new question here and I'll take a look.

Comment: thank you!! I partially solved the issue but I have another pain point in my code. I just posted a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75948598/matching-part-of-column-names-in-2-dataframes-python