# Matching part of column names in 2 dataframes (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, function, string-matching

I'm currently working on a function EWMA which has to be applied to the columns of the p1 dataframe. The formula of the EWMA is splitted in 2 cases: For the min_Date in p1 I have to compute the EWMA using the sample standard deviation of previous dates contained in the dataframe 'seed'; for all the other cases, the EWMA column has to be computed using the i-1 EWMA. I the following issue:

I want the code as automated as it's possible and I need to write in the first line of the function a code which matches the beginning part of each stock with the value of the sample standard deviation contained in seed dataframe. To be more clear, I need to write in the code that the

when the p1[Date] = min_Date :
p1 [StockA_EWMA] = (lam * (Standard dev of seed(Stock_A)**2) + ((1-lam)*(p1(StockA_Ret)**2))

while in other cases:
p1 [StockA_EWMA] = (lam * (p1[i-1,StockA_EWMA]**2) + ((1-lam)*(p1(StockA_Ret)**2))

My biggest issue is to find a way to automatically match the Standard deviation (contained in seed) and the Return (contained in p1) based on the name of the stock (which is the beginning part of the name of each column).
Worth to mention that the standard deviation contained in seed are all equal if we look at each stock.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from numpy import log as ln
from finvizfinance.quote import finvizfinance
from pandas.io.html import read_html
import json
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import log as ln
import statistics
import math
from datetime import datetime as dt
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
from datetime import timedelta
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
#pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

p1 = yf.download(['FTSEMIB.MI','ENEL.MI','CPR.MI','RACE.MI'], period='max')['Close']

p1=p1.fillna(0)

p1.reset_index(inplace=True)

'''Definizione del Holding Period'''

t=p1.iloc[-1,0]
LookB1=(t - relativedelta(years=5))
if (LookB1 in p1['Date'].values):
    LP= (t - relativedelta(years=5))
else:
    LP=(p1.loc[(pd.to_datetime(p1['Date'])
                     - pd.to_datetime(LookB1)).abs().idxmin(),
    'Date'])

seed_date = LP - timedelta(days=90)

if (seed_date in p1['Date'].values):
    seed = (LP - relativedelta(days=90))
else:
    seed =(p1.loc[(pd.to_datetime(p1['Date'])
                     - pd.to_datetime(seed_date)).abs().idxmin(),
    'Date'])


'''Returns function'''

def Return(x):
    return ln(x.div(x.shift(3)))

p1 = p1.infer_objects()   #to convert columns that contain only float but have somehow gotten a Series dtype of object
RetCol = [col for col in p1.columns if p1[col].dtype=='float64']
p1[[f'{col}_Ret' for col in RetCol]] = p1[RetCol].apply(Return)

p1=p1.fillna(0)
print(p1)

def SD(x):
    return statistics.stdev(x)


seed=p1[p1['Date'].isin(pd.date_range(seed,LP))]
seed.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
seed=seed[[col for col in seed.columns if '_Ret' in col]]
seed[[f'{col}_SD' for col in RetCol]] = seed.apply(SD)
print(seed)


p1=p1[p1['Date'].isin(pd.date_range(LP,t))]
p1.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
p1=p1[[col for col in p1.columns if '_Ret'in col]]
print(p1)

lam=0.98
p1.reset_index(inplace=True)
min_Date = p1['Date'].min()
print(p1)


'''EWMA Computation'''

def EWMA(X):
    for i in p1.index:
        for col in seed.columns:
            if p1.loc[i, 'Date'] == min_Date:
                return p1.loc[i,f'{col}_EWMA']==math.sqrt((lam*(seed.loc[i,f'{col}_SD']**2) + (1-lam) * (p1.loc[i,f'{col}_Ret']**2)))
            else:
                return p1.loc[i,f'{col}_EWMA']==math.sqrt(lam*((p1.loc[i-1,f'{col}_EWMA'])**2)+(1-lam)*(p1.loc[i,f'{col}_Ret']**2))

p1[[f'{col}_EWMA' for col in p1]] = p1.apply(EWMA)
print(p1)
```

Comment: What is currently going wrong?

Comment: I have a key error on the first EWMA Column ('CPR.MI_Ret_EWMA'): it seems coming from p1[[f'{col}_EWMA' for col in p1]] = p1.apply(EWMA). 

What I think is that I did not write properly the EWMA function to set all the features I wrote above.